# Command to find nearest printer

Tags: powershell, network-programming, wmi, printers

Please share me the command to find the nearest printer to the machine in an organization.

The command can be anything from WMI,Powershell etc,

Comment: Not possible. Printers are not required to specify their location and anyway, a lift may be broken.

Comment: try the location field - http://serverfault.com/questions/432164/what-is-location-field-in-active-directory-used-for

Comment: Sure it's 'possible', but depending on the size of the organisation, a better way to achieve it may be with 'follow me' printing.

Answer (score 1):

Divide your building into an 8x8 chessboard labelled A-H and 1-8, maybe also by floor too. Then have your network administrator name your printers according to location, eg Floor 3-B6.

Comment: Creativity of side-channel answers never cease to surprise me. That would be some workaround ;-)

Comment: @Koliat: I am not sure I like the "side-channel" moniker. I don't see any other answers. As far as I know, printers are unable to report their location themselves, so any solution is going to require the Network Administrator to attach some type of location (be it building/floor/room, or something synced from an asset database, so why not a grid - it is simple and easily understood. I guess a link to the coporate intranet with a "Printer Location Map" would be my next best answer.

Comment: Not that I meant it is not valid, and by "side-channel" I just meant a good idea which will work and is not something that is standardized i.e. in documentation ;-). As for some idea to check that, if the network structure in the organization is linear, a tracert hops may help to determine the "nearest" printer. Only of course if network isn't mixed up in VPNs which is most probably the case.